# How to generate a PNG image from a dot file format with Graphviz

Tags: java, queue, graphviz

I have a java class that implements a priority queue. Then I have a class test that generates a graph like this:

```
digraph G {
Milan  (0.0)       ->     Turin  (1.2)       
Milan  (0.0)       ->     Montreal  (7.0)       
Turin  (1.2)       ->     Paris  (5.8)       
Turin  (1.2)       ->     Tokyo  (2.2)       
}
```

This graph is saved in a file called "queue".

Now I wish that this graph was displayed in a PNG image using Graphviz. 
So the last call of my test files (after you have created and filled the queue with priority) is:

```
queue.toString("queue");
```

All right. The toString method is the following:

```
public void toString(String fileDot){
    try {
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(fileDot); 
        PrintStream Output = new PrintStream(file); 
        Output.print(this.printQueue()); 
        Output.close(); 
        File f = new File(fileDot); 
        String arg1 = f.getAbsolutePath(); 
        String arg2 = arg1 + ".png"; 
        String[] c = {"dot", "-Tpng", arg1, "-o", arg2};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(c); 
        int err = p.waitFor(); 
    }
    catch(IOException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e2) {
        System.out.println(e2);
    }
}

private String printQueue() throws IOException {
    String g = new String("");
    char c = '"';
    g = g.concat("digraph G {\n");
    if(isEmpty()) 
        g = g.concat("    " + "Empty priority queue.");
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
            if(heap[2 * i] != null) { 
                g = g.concat("" + heap[i].elem + "  (" + heap[i].prior + ")   " + "   " + " -> " + "    " + "" + heap[i * 2].elem + "  (" + heap[i * 2].prior + ")       \n" );
                if(heap[2 * i + 1] != null) 
                    g = g.concat("" + heap[i].elem + "  (" + heap[i].prior + ")   " + "   " + " -> " + "    " + "" + heap[i * 2 + 1].elem + "  (" + heap[i * 2 + 1].prior + ")       \n" ); 
            } 
        } //end for
    } //end else  
    g = g.concat("}");
    return g;   
}
```

Why is not generated image .png? Where am I wrong? 
Of course I installed Graphviz. 
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When I ran the `.dot` file above through `dot` at the command line, I got:

```
$ dot -Tpng queue.dot -oqueue.png
Warning: queue.dot:2: syntax error in line 2 near '('
```

Thus, the parenthesised numbers in the node names are not valid in `dot` syntax. If you remove them, I expect the `.png` file would be created successfully. If you need the parenthesised numbers in your output, I suggest looking up node labels in the GraphViz documentation.

I'd also note that `toString()` does not seem like a particularly clear name for a function that creates a `.png` file so changing the name of the function might be advisable.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the wrong format of the label. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dot`'s `-O` option instead of `-o`. According to `dot -?` here's what it does:

- Automatically generate an output filename based on the input filename with a .'format' appended. (Causes all -ofile options to be ignored.)

So you could change

```
String[] c = {"dot", "-Tpng", arg1, "-o", arg2};
```

to

```
String[] c = {"dot", "-Tpng", arg1, "-O"};
```